# get the request parameter from url with & symbol

Tags: java, jsp

I am trying to get the request parameter which has '&' sybol in starting like:- 
`http://localhost:8080/simple.jsp?my=&234587`

On other page I'm getting it like `String value=request.getParameter("my"); 
value.substring(0,4);`

I want to get &234, please suggest i am not getting any value.

Thanks,
Ars

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this example you have not one, but two parameters:

1. my
2. 234

`234` is not a value here. The `&` separates query parameters. If you need that ampersand to be part of the value of `my`, it needs to be escaped in the URL as `%26`.

Comment: Thanks but i cant modify the url its coming from third party tool i.e. i cant change my self the '&' sign to %26, do we have any code to get the complete url from address bar so that we can replace the & manually with %26 and then perform the opration?

Comment: If you get it like that from a third party tool, file a bug with them. It is **not** compliant if it is meant to be a value of `my`.

Comment: okay is there any way that i can get only the value after ampersand i.e. 234587 ???

Answer (score 2):

thanks for resonse i found the answer, I used `request.getQueryString();` to get the whole string i.e. &234587 and then parsed it accordingly.

:)

Thanks once again.

Answer (score 0):

You will most likely have to encode the '&' in the url:

`http://localhost:8080/simple.jsp?my=%26234587`

Comment: Thanks but i cant modify the url its coming from third party tool i.e. i cant change my self the '&' sign to %26, do we have any code to get the complete url from address bar so that we can replace the & manually with %26 and then perform the opration?

Answer (score 0):

If you will be handling only Get request. You can write something like this.

```
String requestURI=request.getRequestURI();
String pContent=requestURI.split("?")[1];
String[] pArray= pContent.split("&");
String value="";                  
for (int i=0 ;i<pArray.length;i++) {
  if(pArray[i].equals("my"+"=")){
   value="&" + pArray[i+1];
   break;
  }
}
```